# Fragment transaction from main activity doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, view, fragmenttransaction

I'm writing my first android app using fragments but I can't figure out why it doesn't change view from main activity to fragment.
This is my mainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button fragment1_BTN, fragment2_BTN;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fragment1_BTN = findViewById(R.id.frag1_btn);
    fragment2_BTN = findViewById(R.id.frag2_btn);

    fragment1_BTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            replaceFragment(new Frag1());
        }
    });

    fragment2_BTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            replaceFragment(new Frag2());
        }
    });
}

private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    transaction.commit();
}}
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/therapists_btn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
        android:text="button 1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/patients_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/patients_btn"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/teal_700"
        android:text="button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/therapists_btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout> </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The problem is that when I click on button 1 I see the view of first fragment and also of main activity.
How can I see only the fragment view?

Answer (score 0):

your `frameLayout` container for `Fragment`s is placed before `LinearLayout`, `Fragment`s `View` is loaded into it and is visible, but also rest of `View`s is drawn after that (as order in XML) on top of it. just `setVisibility(View.GONE)` for this `LinearLayout` when you are loading `Fragment` (set for it some `id` and use `findViewById` as for buttons). another approach would be to put your `LinearLayout` inside container - you are using `replace` method so `Fragment` will remove your buttons, but in that case these are gone forever then and you don't have an easy option for bringing them back (with your current code - only whole `Activity` restart)

it would be way better (by design) if your `Activity` wouldn't have these buttons at all, only container, and on start would check if container has anything loaded (e.g. `getChildCount()==0`), if not then load some initial `Fragment` for preventing displaying empty `Activity`

Comment: Now I have this in my 'activity_main.xml' : "<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>"

Comment: But the result of getChildCount is 1. how is it possible?

Comment: at start there must be 0 childs (when inflating `View`, using `setContentView`). it will be 1 when `Fragment` is loaded into it, or this frame will contain `LinearLayout`. btw. it would be better to edit question with current code, if XML doesn't have buttons then how do you load any fragment or check if container is empty?

Comment: note that you can also use `removeAllViews()` on container, but this will fit for removing `LinearLayout`, don't use this for removing `Fragment`, its more complicated ;)